# jqGrid Date column sort does not work with sorttype:'date'

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in MVC 4 to display data. I am having a grids with date/ datetime column in it. I am returning C# `DateTime` variable data for grid date column; which is displaying fine with the `formatoption: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y'}` for date column & `formatoption: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A'}` for datetime column. but the sorting of this column does not reflect when user clicks column header. 
here is the `colModel` for date column

```js
{
    name: 'TestOrderDate', index: 'TestOrderDate', formatter: 'date',
    sorttype: 'date', width: 90, align: 'center', fixed: true,
    formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' }
},
```

& for datetime column

```js
{
    name: 'TestOrderDate', index: 'TestOrderDate', formatter: 'date',
    sorttype: 'date', width: 90, align: 'center', fixed: true,
    formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A' }
},
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in `colModel` due to which sort behavior not working.

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` option?

Comment: I am using loadonce :true setting & jason datatype for grid.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Could you change the format of date returned from the server to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? It's recommended format independent on the problem which you explain. In the case you can use `srcformat: "ISO8601Long"`.

Comment: Well I was previously formatting date to string on server side, but its my clients recommendation that i need to use data type for returning data to grid as per the data returned from stored procedures. i.e. for date time value I need to return c# DateTime value in the record of jqGrid. Cant I go with the current setting?

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use?**

Comment: Do you like retro? the version is 2.5 years old. I recommend you to update to version 4.5.4 published yesterday. It contains full new version of parsing dates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I cannot immediately switch to new version. It will be great-full if you provide me fix for this in my current version.

Comment: I will definitely switch to newer version once the development is complete & before its first release.

Comment: @Oleg For switching to newer version; is it just changing jqGrid js & css files or more than that. If only I need to replace my existing js files then which are those files?

Comment: To use jqGrid you need include 3 files: `ui.jqgrid.css`, `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) - see [the example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file). So you need download the last version of jqGrid from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) (click on "Download" button on the bottom) and replace `ui.jqgrid.css` (with `ellipsis-xbl.xml` required sometimes) and `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). You can use [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Trirand.jqGrid/) alternative

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have upgraded to latest version. Now it is working as expected for date column. But can you brief me on ellipsis-xbl.xml file. I haven't included that file in my solution; & if necessary to include then in which directory I should include. And one more thing can you post further as answer so that I can mark it as answer or how can I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: You are right. The file will be not used in the current version of jqGrid. It was used for old versions of Firefox/Mozilla browser only. Compare [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L139) from `ui.jqgrid.css` of version 4.3.1 and [the corresponding line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L148) of the current version. I think that one can remove the file `ellipsis-xbl.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you update 2.5 years old version 4.1.1 to version 4.5.4. It contains new implementation of date parsing. To sort the column having `sorttype:'date'` option jqGrid first parse (unformat) the string displayed in the grid. Formats like `'m/d/Y h:i:s A'` not supported for parsing (and sorting) in old versions of jqGrid.

The versions of jqGrid starting with 4.3.2 don't need the file `ellipsis-xbl.xml`. It was used in early versions to display ellipsis in old versions of Mozilla/Firefox browsers. [The line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L139) of `ui.jqgrid.css` was replaced to [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L148) starting with 4.3.2.

Comment: Please review the Question edit summary & suggest solution for my problem.

Comment: @Shaggy: Sorry, but your last changes of the question seems that you try to post **new question** really. The main goal of stackoverflow is *sharing common questions and the corresponding answers*. Any commutative questions reduce effective of searching engine and other user can't good find the same on stackoverflow. So please ask always **separate questions**.

Comment: @Shaggy: If I correctly understand what you need is the usage of `$.jgrid.parseDate` or ` $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", cellval, opts, rowObject, action)` inside of `LoadCPAPFollowUpDialog`. I will post my answer after you separate your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I deleted the changes in this question & posted new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292200/jqgrid-datetime-column-returns-string-value-like-date1380565800000-instead-of) with the solution I implemented for it. Please tell me whether it right way or not.

Comment: Hi, you helped me resolving jqGrid issues. Thanks for your help so far. Currently I am facing another problem of action method not called with server side paging.Please go through the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357356/jqgrid-url-not-getting-called-with-server-side-paging-sorting-postdata-form) & suggest me solution for it.

Comment: @Shaggy: I'v seen the question, but the description is unclear for me. First of all it's unclear *how* you use `DefineGrid`. Why you need a function which can be used *once only*. Moreover I don't see that you implemented server side paging in any way (`startIndex` will be not used). `DMEUploadDetails` is also unknown. Is `Year` and  `Month` are the only properties of `DMEUploadDetails`? I can continue with more questions... Additionally I suppose that you need to use properties of `postData` defined as functions (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935)).

Comment: I changes the definition of Grid & action method to pass indivisual postData parameter instead of model object. Now its working. But I have another problem related to it. I have updated the question please review it & provide me solution for this requirement. Its urgent so if you could reply soon I will be greatful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

jqGrid does not support sorting by datetime but by just date. Hence you can use alternative as given in its PDF i.e. shown in below example.   If your data in grid is already sorted by Date and Time , and you also have a column with the Index of all rows like in Numbers as 1, 2, 3, .... n . The you can sort the datetime on the Index Column. This will always ensure asc or desc order for datetime.

You can sort the jqGrid's DATE and time or date by another Column content. Such as given in example below on onSortCOl:

```
            onSortCol: function(name,index) { if(name == 'createDateTime') { jQuery("#viewNotesGrid").setGridParam({sortname:"ID"}); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix is to trick jqGrid to load an int but display a date.

my colModel is
{name: 'startDt', index: 'startDt', width: 50, sortable: true, sorttype: '**int**', formatter: '**date**', formatoptions: {srcformat: "**U**", newformat: "d-M-Y"}},

When you load the grid data, convert your date string to milliseconds divided by 1000.  So in my case startDt is a very large integer value.

If your date is a blank/null, just load the grid with ''.

What's nice is that the blank/null is now sorted properly.  Ascending has blank/null(s) first, Descending has blank/null(s) last.